# Select Which User Has More Products

Tags: mysql

I have a table `products`:

```
id    user    products
1     user1   product
2     user2   product
3     user1   product
4     user3   product
5     user4   product
```

Now I want to get which user has the most products (user1)

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE ...
```

Any suggestion for SQL query?

Comment: Do you mean the user with the most number of occurrences, in a way? Does the `products` column has an effect or it is dumb as in the example?

Comment: Yes the products column is a an example

Answer (score 2):

You could du something like this:

```
SELECT `p`.`user` FROM `products` as p GROUP BY `user` ORDER BY count(id) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but would you please write me the full statement? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "full statement"? The statement above only returns the user with the most products, and if i get your question right that's exactly what you want?